# Do isomorphic graphs have same adjacency matrix upto some permutation of both rows and columns?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, soft-question, adjacency-matrix

Suppose $2$ graphs are isomorphic,then if we write the adjacency matrix of the second graph by arranging the rows and column in similar way to corresponding arrangement of vertices of first graph,then the matrix should remain identical.In general,these two matrices should be equivalent upto congruence $A\rho B\iff A=P^tBP$ for some $P$ non-singular.Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's essentially the definition of isomorphic for graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the permutation is the one induced by the graph isomorphism on the vertices and vice versa. It's really a restatement of the graph isomorphism, $P$ is not-only non-singular but a permutation matrix, and use $P^{T} =P^{-1}$ for those.

Comment: permutation matrix means?

Comment: @KishalaySarkar Look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix) first?